# MPMoviePlayerViewController can't set current playback time

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to set currentPlaybackTime property of the MPMoviePlayerController in MPMoviePlayerViewController to make it resume playing video (HLS stream) from the time, it was stopped when the app resigned active. Here's my code:

```
    //the functinon that sets playback time
    - (void)setCurrentPlayTime:(NSNumber *)time {
        if (self.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime < [time floatValue] - 10.0) {
            [self.moviePlayer setCurrentPlaybackTime:(NSTimeInterval)[time floatValue]];
        }
    }

    //app did become active callback
    - (void) applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
        if (!isnan(_curPlayTime) && _curPlayTime > 0.0) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(setCurrentPlayTime:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_curPlayTime] afterDelay:0.1];
        }
    }

    //player load state did change callback
    -(void)playerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {   
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = notification.object;
    MPMovieLoadState loadState = player.loadState;  
if (loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) {
        if (!isnan(_curPlayTime) && _curPlayTime > 0.0) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(setCurrentPlayTime:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:_curPlayTime] afterDelay:0.1];
            _curPlayTime = 0.0;
        }
}
```

When I just tap Home button and then reopen the app, and also if I get incoming call but decline it, it works. But if I answer an incoming call, after I finish the call, playing starts from the 0.0 ignoring setCurrentPlaybackTime method call. Does anybody know, where's the problem and may be any example how it should be done to work correct?

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is the issue but the selector you are searching for is setCurrentPlayTime not setCurrentPlay**back**Time.

Comment: haven't found currentPlayTime property or setCurrentPlayTime neither in MPMoviePlayerController interface nor in MPMediaPlayback Protocol. Could you please give a link to documentation for it.

Comment: property currentPlaybackTime  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Its setter is hence setCurrentPlaybackTime

Comment: So it's still currentPlay*back*Time, not currentPlayTime.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for answer and trying to help. The project, I'm working on got huge changes and player controller also got significant changes and now I do not have such problem. Still don't have any idea, what was the problem and how to fix it (The main thing I changed is that now I use MPMoviePlayerController in UIViewController instead of subclassing MPMoviePlayerViewController) but no need for the answer anymore (and no way to check if the answer is helpful).

Comment: Yeah, noticed that you using currentPlayTime for your class. That confused me. Sorry I couldn't help!